# In ASP.NET MVC, how can I match URLs to a route if an URL segment contains literal dashes and one of the parameter constraints allows dashes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Given this route:

```
{prefix}-{id}-{postfix}
```

There is one URL segment, and 3 so-called parameters: `prefix`, `id` and `postfix`. Any URL with 3 dashes will generally match this route (if the parameter values match the constraints defined for those parameters). However, as soon as I define, for the 3rd parameters, a regex constraint that allows dashes, the entire route no longer matches.

For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    url: "{prefix}-{id}-{postfix}", 
    constraints: new {
        prefix: "test",
        id: "42"
        postfix: "[a-z-]+"
    }
);
```

This will **not** match a request to ~/test-42-hello-world/

And by that I mean that the ASP.NET routing engine does not even consider this route for this URL. I know that because I replaced one of the constraints with a custom `IRouteConstraint` and put a breakpoint inside its `Match()` method, and my breakpoint was never hit.

I would like to know if what I want to do is possible.

If not, I would really appreciate a link to some documentation (or source) that I can look at to understand the reason this doesn't work.

Comment: How did you solve this problem? Did you find a way to use dashes in the segment so parameter with value `hello-world` is recognized properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite simply, your URL doesn't match in this case. The [url patterns documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#url_patterns) explains it, but unfortunately not very well.

> In a URL pattern, you define placeholders by enclosing them in braces ( { and } ). You can define more than one placeholder in a segment, but they must be separated by a literal value. For example, {language}-{country}/{action} is a valid route pattern. However, {language}{country}/{action} is not a valid pattern, because there is no literal value or delimiter between the placeholders. **Therefore, routing cannot determine where to separate the value for the language placeholder from the value for the country placeholder.**

The same logic holds true when determining what literal values are. Once a value is used as a literal, the framework won't be able to differentiate a literal from a placeholder that contains the literal.

The first thing the routing engine looks a is the URL pattern that is defined. This happens before any constraints are even considered.

Your URL pattern contains the following in order.

1. A `{prefix}` placeholder
2. A literal `-` (dash) character
3. An `{id}` placeholder
4. A literal `-` (dash) character
5. A `{postfix}` placeholder

Your incoming virtual path `test-42-hello-world` is compared with each piece.

1. A `{prefix}` placeholder **Matches `test`**
2. A literal `-` (dash) character **Matches `-`**
3. An `{id}` placeholder **Matches `42`**
4. A literal `-` (dash) character **Matches `-`**
5. A `{postfix}` placeholder **Matches `hello`**

The problem is that there is now extra information at the end of the virtual path that does not match, namely `-world`. This makes the entire URL pattern not match.